# onchange for the asp.net textbox is not working

Tags: asp.net

i have one text box beside which there is one date picker and one dropdownlist in one user control which i'm using in one aspx page.I want to enable the regular field validator of the dropdownlist if we select the date from the datepicker in the textbox otherwise it should it should be false.
So how i should go ??

Comment: Please show your code and further explain how the title of your question reflects your statements

Comment: actually before i was using the onchange event in the client side,but i was not going through in that,So is there any other way to proceed with/?????/

Answer (score 0):

Would something basically like this work for you:

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  
         OnTextChanged="MyTextBox_TextChanged">
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MyValidator" runat=server 
        ControlToValidate="MyTextBox" 
        ErrorMessage="Must be in correct format" 
        ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]" /><!-- use whatever regex you need here -->
```

Code behind:

```
protected void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
    MyValidator.IsEnabled = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyTextBox.Text);  
}
```